# Not getting option to install ubuntu on virtualbox

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtualbox 7.0.14 with Windows 10 as host.
After clicking "try or install Ubuntu" " I don't get any option to install Ubuntu instead I just get the Ubuntu screen and curser keeps reloading infinitely.

[image: screenshot-of-virtualbox]

It does not go past this.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the specifications of the host PC (running Windows), e.g. how much RAM you have installed)?